# In Rails console, see "Filter chain halted" messages for contrroller requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making controller requests from my Rails console (e.g. `app.get('/foo')`). Is there a way for me to see "Filter chain halted" messages here in order to zero-in on what's causing the redirects/failures that I see?

*I'm working on Rails 3.2 and 4.2*

Comment: you could try using byebug and going up and down the methods, but I am not sure if byebug is compatible with console

Comment: I don't know, but if you were using byebug, where would you put the breakpoint? Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I would try to put it into contorller and see if it hits at all. Do you have a controller?

Comment: It happens that that isn't an option because of the environment which I've been given to work in, but even if I put a breakpoint into a controller, it's not apparent to me where in a controller I might put a breakpoint that would let me step through the filters. I could put it into some arbitrary filter, but the chain isn't a stack, so there isn't a reasonable way to walk the chain. (It would be extremely noisy.)

Comment: ok is it possible to trigger this error from the app at all? maybe the server can give you some clue. it normally shows which actions/controller/views are triggered/rendered

Comment: What do you mean by 'from the app'? If you mean making a real request to the server, it's not something I've been able to reproduce, but a user with access to different resources in the app has been able to. But I can't use his credentials.

Comment: It seems hard to find the bug if you can't even reproduce it. [This](https://docs.rightscale.com/faq/What_does_Filter_chain_halted_mean_in_my_logs.html) could be helpful. Good look with the error, I am not really familiar with this specific filter halted error.